# Dynamically add element to typed array

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

I can pass a typed array to a constructor and use generics to declare the type. But after getting the object instance (via the constructor call), I want to add a new element to the array. But the dynamic typing methodology I have right now can't incorporate the new element in the array.

Say I have this:

```
type TypeMapping = {
  Boolean: boolean,
  String: string,
  Number: number,
  Integer: number,
}

export enum Type {
  Boolean = 'Boolean',
  String = 'String',
  Number = 'Number',
  Integer = 'Integer',
}

export interface ElemType {
  name: string,
  type: keyof TypeMapping,
}

export const asOptions = <K extends keyof any, T extends Array<{ name: K, type: keyof TypeMapping }>>(t: T) => t;

export type OptionsToType<T extends Array<ElemType>>
  = { [K in T[number]['name']]: TypeMapping[Extract<T[number], { name: K }>['type']] }


export class Foo<T extends Array<ElemType>> {

  bar: T;
  baz: OptionsToType<T>;

  constructor(t: T){
    this.bar = t;
  }

  add(t: ElemType){
    this.bar.push(t);
  }

}


const list = asOptions([{name: 'xxx', type: Type.Boolean}]);

const f = new Foo(list);

f.baz.xxx = false; // compiles


f.add({name: 'uuu', type: Type.String});
f.baz.uuu = 'z';   // does not compile (as we would expect)
```

It works wonderfully until the last two lines. If I use the `add()`  method to push a new element onto the array, there is really no way for the type system to incorporate.

Is there some magic way I can update the type of the bar/baz members on the instance?

Comment: I think you are out of luck with mutating an existing object, although if you change the `add` method to take a `U extends ElemType` and return a new `Foo<(T[number] | U)[]>`, it might work.  Why do you want to add options dynamically?  Maybe we can help you find another solution.

Comment: probably not that necessary to add options dynamically, but just curious to see if it is possible